# EF Core 5 and FromSqlRaw with inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, rawsql

I want to use a `FromSqlRaw` query with view models and inheritance between them.
I created two example view models:

```
public class SummaryVM 
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class DistrictVM : SummaryVM 
{
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }
}
```

My `DbContext` has this content:

```
public DbSet<SummaryVM> SummaryVMs { get; set; }
public DbSet<DistrictVM> DistrictVMs { get; set; }
...
modelBuilder.Entity<SummaryVM>().HasNoKey();
```

My query:

```
return await _context.DistritVMs.FromSqlRaw(query).ToListAsync();
```

but I get an error:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'. Invalid column name 'DistrictName'

I know this is due to the TPH pattern and I can solve this problem if I do not use inheritance yet how I can use these two tables with inheritance without TPH, please?

**SOLUTION**
I had to create a base class which is not registered as entity:

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class SummaryVM : BaseClass
{
}

public class DistrictVM : BaseClass
{
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**
I had to create a base class which is not registered as entity:

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class SummaryVM : BaseClass
{
}

public class DistrictVM : BaseClass
{
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }
}
```